# docker cannot build image mac

Tags: docker, macos, apple-m1

My mac is Apple M1

Content in my dockerfile:

```
 FROM --platform=linux/amd64 golang:1.18
 
 RUN set -x; \   export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive; \   echo "deb
 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bpaquet/zeromq4-precise/ubuntu precise main "
 /etc/apt/sources.list \   && apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys FF160426C4832F92 \   &&
 apt-get update \   && apt-get install -y \
     libzmq1=4.0.4-bpa~precise1 \
     libzmq-dev=4.0.4-bpa~precise1 \
     pkg-config
 
 ENV PATH /go/bin:$PATH ENV GOPROJECTPATH /go/src/emitter COPY .
 $GOPROJECTPATH WORKDIR $GOPROJECTPATH
 
 RUN go get -v
 
 CMD ["bash"]
```

but once I run build image command:

```
docker build --tag docker-emitter-org .
```

I have this error in my terminal

```
[+] Building 52.9s (6/9)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 606B                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/golang:1.18                                                                                                 1.8s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/golang:1.18@sha256:040bc0980888e2df09499c73156f3f869d843b7033d11b465fee7f1a358a494a                                          33.6s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/golang:1.18@sha256:040bc0980888e2df09499c73156f3f869d843b7033d11b465fee7f1a358a494a                                           0.0s
 => => sha256:040bc0980888e2df09499c73156f3f869d843b7033d11b465fee7f1a358a494a 2.36kB / 2.36kB                                                                 0.0s
 => => sha256:23858da423a6737f0467fab0014e5b53009ea7405d575636af0c3f100bbb2f10 55.03MB / 55.03MB                                                               8.4s
 => => sha256:a42821cd14fb31c4aa253203e7f8e34fc3b15d69ce370f1223fbbe4252a64202 10.88MB / 10.88MB                                                               5.3s
 => => sha256:ebd59a91af0c61cf28a22a9651ffd45612848bdcc1a43c2c3063825ba2e613fc 1.80kB / 1.80kB                                                                 0.0s
 => => sha256:f81bafb819d5b520ab919b42e5925c4b32b62241fc1d036036d9bb5aa2f522d1 7.10kB / 7.10kB                                                                 0.0s
 => => sha256:326f452ade5c33097eba4ba88a24bd77a93a3d994d4dc39b936482655e664857 5.16MB / 5.16MB                                                                 3.1s
 => => sha256:8471b75885efc7790a16be5328e3b368567b76a60fc3feabd6869c15e175ee05 54.58MB / 54.58MB                                                              16.2s
 => => sha256:b7aa120dd02d9fa75bb50861103f7837514028ea6f06e3e821b8c47c2c10d386 85.96MB / 85.96MB                                                              23.0s
 => => extracting sha256:23858da423a6737f0467fab0014e5b53009ea7405d575636af0c3f100bbb2f10                                                                      1.6s
 => => sha256:5cc67fe6144b8a2d33963edb62297bdaa3f968746061866b48db3f3125e68734 141.88MB / 141.88MB                                                            29.3s
 => => extracting sha256:326f452ade5c33097eba4ba88a24bd77a93a3d994d4dc39b936482655e664857                                                                      0.1s
 => => extracting sha256:a42821cd14fb31c4aa253203e7f8e34fc3b15d69ce370f1223fbbe4252a64202                                                                      0.2s
 => => extracting sha256:8471b75885efc7790a16be5328e3b368567b76a60fc3feabd6869c15e175ee05                                                                      1.7s
 => => sha256:cd3416ecab879296d41843948ae859cadb4bd4300a60b23abef443645845ab4a 156B / 156B                                                                    16.4s
 => => extracting sha256:b7aa120dd02d9fa75bb50861103f7837514028ea6f06e3e821b8c47c2c10d386                                                                      2.2s
 => => extracting sha256:5cc67fe6144b8a2d33963edb62297bdaa3f968746061866b48db3f3125e68734                                                                      3.8s
 => => extracting sha256:cd3416ecab879296d41843948ae859cadb4bd4300a60b23abef443645845ab4a                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 876B                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => ERROR [2/5] RUN set -x;   export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive;   echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bpaquet/zeromq4-precise/ubuntu precise main " >> /  17.5s
------
 > [2/5] RUN set -x;   export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive;   echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bpaquet/zeromq4-precise/ubuntu precise main " >> /etc/apt/sources.list   && apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys FF160426C4832F92   && apt-get update   && apt-get install -y     libzmq1=4.0.4-bpa~precise1     libzmq-dev=4.0.4-bpa~precise1     pkg-config:
#4 0.202 + export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
#4 0.207 + echo deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bpaquet/zeromq4-precise/ubuntu precise main
#4 0.208 + apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys FF160426C4832F92
#4 0.897 Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
#4 1.397 Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.aCEKfc6dIj/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys FF160426C4832F92
#4 1.841 gpg: key FF160426C4832F92: public key "Launchpad PPA for Bertrand Paquet" imported
#4 1.879 gpg: Total number processed: 1
#4 1.879 gpg:               imported: 1
#4 5.851 + apt-get update
#4 6.159 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease [116 kB]
#4 6.193 Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bpaquet/zeromq4-precise/ubuntu precise InRelease
#4 6.251 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [48.4 kB]
#4 6.251 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [44.1 kB]
#4 6.264 Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bpaquet/zeromq4-precise/ubuntu precise Release [11.9 kB]
#4 6.354 Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bpaquet/zeromq4-precise/ubuntu precise Release.gpg [316 B]
#4 7.634 Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages [8184 kB]
#4 9.254 Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 Packages [184 kB]
#4 10.32 Get:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates/main amd64 Packages [2596 B]
#4 11.57 Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bpaquet/zeromq4-precise/ubuntu precise Release.gpg
#4 14.66 Reading package lists...
#4 16.99 W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/bpaquet/zeromq4-precise/ubuntu precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: E9F21DF686E307024F2EE2B7FF160426C4832F92
#4 16.99 E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/bpaquet/zeromq4-precise/ubuntu precise Release' is not signed.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c set -x;   export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive;   echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bpaquet/zeromq4-precise/ubuntu precise main " >> /etc/apt/sources.list   && apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys FF160426C4832F92   && apt-get update   && apt-get install -y     libzmq1=4.0.4-bpa~precise1     libzmq-dev=4.0.4-bpa~precise1     pkg-config]: exit code: 100
```

it says

> GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/bpaquet/zeromq4-precise/ubuntu
> precise Release: The following signatures were invalid:
> E9F21DF686E307024F2EE2B7FF160426C4832F92
> #4 16.99 E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/bpaquet/zeromq4-precise/ubuntu precise
> Release' is not signed.

I really do not know what it mean and wondering how to fix and pass the build.

thanks

Comment: You can add `--allow-unauthenticated` to `apt-get install`. However you should better check why the validation fails in the first place.

Comment: tried: `&& apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated ` but same error